# CollectionViewCell image restored to original image on scroll?

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button is a collectionViewCell. When the button is clicked, its image is changed. But when I scroll in my UICollectionView, the changed image reverts back to the original one.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have a cell reuse issue. Please show the code that you put in the cellForItemAtIndexPath datasource

Answer (score 0):

On each time scrolling the collection, cell created again so the image is changing.
Use a boolean or any other property that will check which image should  appear.

Comment: I am new to coding. Can you please give me an example how to do this or sample code